# github can't invite exist outside collaborator to another repository when there is no seats left

Tags: github, roles

(I'm not a native speaker of English.Please forgive my terrible english.)

I have a private organization on github like this:
https://github.com/xxx-technology
this organization includes two repositories:
**repository A
repository B**

I invited haha@gmail.com as an outside collaborator to **repository A**.
Succeed and ocupied the last seat left.
Now my organization have no more seats left.

After a few days, I want to invite the same people(haha@gmail.com) to **repository B**.But when I try it,I got an error which said "**You must purchase at least one more seat to invite this user as a collaborator.**"

As I know one outside collaborator just ocupy one seat.

So how can I invite an exist outside collaborator to a new repository when there is no seats left.
Would love some help!

Comment: Have you tried inviting them to a team on the organization that has access to both A and B instead?

Comment: Not yet,we don't use team for now.We just want to add an exsit outside collaborator to anthoer repository directly.

Comment: I know that. I'm suggesting that a team would be an easier way to have this member in both repositories. Otherwise you're going to have to pay for a second seat.

Comment: Thank you.We will consider that way by inviting people into a team.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry,I solved this problem by asking one of my friends.

To invite an exist outside collaborator to a new repository when there is no seats left.

You just need to invite him by **his github** **Name** **instead of his email address**.